# fast map loading issue with multiple markers in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problem in loading map with multiple marker in samsung epic.map will display after some time.pls give me the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Google maps are dynamically loaded from internet. This is where the delay comes from. Check you internet connection.

Comment: yes I have checked its perfact but the problem is when map is going to open at the same time will try to load multiple marker which cause map slowdown,pls give me the desire solution to resolved this issue

Answer (score -1):

If you are using map only for marker display purpose use lite map special feature by google map [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite)

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:cameraZoom="13"
map:mapType="normal"
map:liteMode="true"/>
```

**map:liteMode="true"** it will make map in lite mode with some [limitation](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?hl=en)
  
AND

For too many marker go with clustering of marker [google link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?csw=1#markerclusterer)
clustering will increase readability of map
**BEFORE CLUSTER**

[image]

**AFTER CLUSTER**
[image]